# How to return const& from std::visit?

Tags: c++, variant

I have encountered what i consider to be a strange situation with `std::visit` and `overloaded` which is giving me a compiler error. To illustrate what i am trying to do I have an example using std::visit 3 different ways.

- Approach 1, calling `std::visit` directly on a variant which returns a `T const&`,
- Approach 2, wrapping the `std::visit` code in a free function: `T const& fn(variantT const&)`
- Approach 3, wrapping the variant in a structure with an accessor `T const& get_XXX() const`

**My goal** is to be able to wrap the `std::visit` part in a function because in my use case it's not a small piece of code. I have multiple lambda overloads. I don't want to have to duplicate this code in each function that uses the variant and wants to get a property, i want to write it once in some kind of wrapper which i can re-use across multiple translation units (Approach 3 is most preferable to me, then Apporach 2, and all else fails, I will investigate something less pleasing like a macro or something.)

**Can someone explain to me:**

- Why / where `std::visit` is creating a temporary object?
- Is there something I can do differently to prevent this temporary from being created?
- Accepting that a temporary exists for some reason or other, why does the temporary object lifetime extension rule not apply here?

Please consider this minimal example which reproduces the problem I am seeing.

### Minimal example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <variant>

template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };

struct a {
    std::string name;

    std::string const& get_name() const { return name; }
};

struct b {
    std::string name;

    std::string const& get_name() const { return name; }
};

std::string const& visit_get_name(std::variant<a, b> const& data) {
    return std::visit(overloaded{[](auto const& o){return o.get_name();}}, data);
}

struct wrapper {

    std::string const& get_name() const {
        return std::visit(overloaded{[](auto const& o){return o.get_name();}}, data);
    }

    std::variant<a, b> data;
};

int main(int, char**) {
    std::variant<a, b> a_thing{a{"sue"}};
    wrapper a_wrapper{a_thing};

    std::cout << "Approach 1: " << std::visit(overloaded{[](auto const& o){return o.get_name();}}, a_thing);
    std::cout << "Approach 2: " << visit_get_name(a_thing);
    std::cout << "Approach 3: " << a_wrapper.get_name();

    return 0;
}
```

### Compiler:

`GCC 11.2.0`

### Compiler errors:

```
example.cpp: In function 'const string& visit_get_name(const std::variant<a, b>&)':
example.cpp:20:22: error: returning reference to temporary [-Werror=return-local-addr]
   20 |     return std::visit(overloaded{[](auto const& o){return o.get_name();}}, data);
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
example.cpp: In member function 'const string& wrapper::get_name() const':
example.cpp:26:26: error: returning reference to temporary [-Werror=return-local-addr]
   26 |         return std::visit(overloaded{[](auto const& o){return o.get_name();}}, data);
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

### Compiler switches:

```
-Wall 
-Wextra 
-Wshadow 
-Wnon-virtual-dtor 
-Wold-style-cast 
-Wcast-align 
-Wunused 
-Woverloaded-virtual 
-Wpedantic 
-Wconversion 
-Wsign-conversion 
-Wnull-dereference 
-Wdouble-promotion 
-Wformat=2 
-Werror 
-Wmisleading-indentation 
-Wduplicated-cond 
-Wduplicated-branches 
-Wlogical-op 
-std=gnu++20
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default behavior when calling a lambda (or a function for that matter) is to have the value returned by copy. Since your lambda expressions that you pass to `overloaded` return by copy, binding a reference to that in the return type of `visit_get_name` (or `wrapper::get_name`) is not allowed, which is why Approach 2 and 3 fail.

If you want to return by reference, you have to say so (note the explicit `-> auto const &` trailing return type for the lambda), like this:

```
return std::visit(overloaded{[](auto const& o) -> auto const & {
                               return o.get_name();
                             }}, data);
```

(and the same thing for `wrapper::get_name` as well).

This isn't needed for Approach 1, since you're not binding a reference to what's returned.

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dGcvhvfxM).